# Returning an implicitly unwrapped optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm writing a program in Swift which has various functions which *should* always return values, but in some cases cannot, and so the program crashes and alerts the user of the error. To accomplish this, I am using implicitly unwrapped Optionals as return values for my functions, so that error cases can just return nil (even though that code will never be reached). It looks something like this:

```
func giveMeAThing() -> Thing! {
    if !possibleErrorCase() {
        var thing = createAThingForSure()
        return thing
    }
    else {
        crashAndBurn()
        return nil
    }
}
```

Writing this, it feels a bit hacky, so my question is whether or not this is a good use of implicitly unwrapped Optionals in Swift. Is there a better way to structure my code that will avoid this?

Comment: If `giveMeAThing` should truly always return a `Thing` then the method prototype (and return value) should indicate that (`Thing` vs. `Thing!`)  One of the major strengths of Swift is Optional, abandoning that contract is something to be done rarely, if ever.  Also, if you follow Apple's evolution, they're trending away from using implicitly unwrapped optionals except where absolutely required by Objective-C interfaces.  If something should always be a Thing, it should be declared as such.  If something might be a thing, it should be declared as Thing?  New code should never use `Thing!`

Comment: That was my intuition as well (I *know* whether or not I might return nil, it shouldn't have to be implicitly unwrapped), but the compiler obviously won't ignore the fact that I leave out a return. Implicitly unwrapped Optionals always feel ugly to me.

Comment: See matts answer, declare it to return `Thing` and use `assert` (or something similar) to handle the "this should never happen" case.

Comment: Yeah, `fatalError` was what I needed, so I implemented the function using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the piece of the puzzle you are missing is `@noreturn`. If you declare a function as `@noreturn`, the compiler abandons any complaints if you don't fulfill the surrounding contract. Thus you can call such a method and *not* return *any* value, and the compiler will not complain because it knows we are going to die anyway. For example, `fatalError` and `abort` are declared this way.

Thus, the following is legal:

```
func f() -> String {
    fatalError("oooooops")
}
```

That compiles even though we fail to fulfill the contract of returning a value, because `@noreturn` (in the declaration of `fatalError`) tears up the contract and flushes the pieces down the toilet.

Another possible way of approaching the same issue is to use `assert`. This crashes and burns for you if a condition is not met. So, in your example:

```
func giveMeAThing() -> Thing {
    assert(!possibleErrorCase(), "gaaaaah!") // crash and burn if error case
    return createAThingForSure()
}
```

The downside is that by default all asserts succeed in a shipping app. But it's great during development, and after all your shipping app should not be crashing and burning anyway.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I'll be reading up on Attributes now I suppose, looks like that can be very useful...

Comment: @noreturn is part of the answer, as pointed out by matt.  However, it should only rarely be used (perhaps never at an application level)  Instead one of the system functions that are already flagged (in this case `fatalError`) that way should be used.

Comment: @David I agree. If he's really going to crash and burn he should just call `fatalError` or `assert` and be done with it. :) OP, do you know about `assert`?

Comment: @Jumhyn see my discussion of aborting generally in my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_aborting

Comment: I'm using fatalError now, just wrapping it in another function to provide more info about the crash. I do know about assert, but my impression is that it is only for debugging purposes rather than manually triggering a shutdown. I'm writing a command line app with no plans to ship, not an App Store app where crashing is a huge HIG violation.

Comment: Sounds good! Good example of how it is better for your question to ask about what you _really_ want to do; your Optional was a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather write this as

```
func giveMeAThing() -> Thing! {
    if possibleErrorCase() {
        crashAndBurn() // I assume this will not return anyhow
    }
    return createAThingForSure()
}
```

but that's likely just a question of taste.

Comment: Actually, that seems better since it wouldn't actually need the implicitly unwrapped optional at all. That's a nice refactor that I stupidly didn't think of because my actual code is closer to `if canCreateAThing()` and it made more sense to check the positive case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an implicitly unwrapped optional since you don't expect the second case to return any value.

As commenters noted, use `fatalError` in the fail case.